# Install system to Disk on Chip

Tags: linux, installation

I'm looking for an easy way to install linux on a PC104 (x86 no cmov) system with a Disk-on-Chip. It can be a very simple system (BusyBox, etc) or a distro the installs in under 512mb. I just need to boot to a prompt. Does anyone know a simple path to get this done?

I briefly checked out http://narcissus.angstrom-distribution.org/ but was unsure if any of those platforms are appropriate.

Comment: Are you talking about an *original* PC/104, or is this one of the relatively newer ones from 2008, such as the PCIe/104? You're more likely to have supporting drivers if you have a modern PCIe one.

Comment: Also, if you able to connect up a VGA, DVI or HDMI display and a USB controller, you should be able to install Linux just like you'd install it on a normal PC. Make a thumb drive with the Linux install environment on it and boot it up. Failing that, you may be able to install over a serial port, but I've no idea how to actually do that. It all depends on what connectors you have available.

Comment: I can boot from usb but I can't mount the disk-on-chip.

Comment: "can't"? What did you try? Have you researched whether drivers for this "disk-on-chip" are even available for the Linux kernel? If there are no drivers for it, you'd have to write the driver yourself, which would not be easy at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot from a USB stick there are various flavours of linux you could try. I use a small collection of USB sticks (from 64mb to 8Gb) with different Linux distros on them for various tasks. We also use several rather old machines with minimal RAM and no hard disks that boot and run off USB sticks to do simple tasks like piping data from an SDR receiver into the LAN. Running live OS on USB stick has many advantages. No HD = less noise, less heat, less power.

You may well be operating with limited onboard RAM, and it sounds like you are trying to locate the OS in a flash drive? or something along those lines, in which case the 'frugal' installation method may be what you need.

Try DSL Linux, (under 50Mb, I use it on a 64Mb USB stick on an old 486-DX2 66MHz remote system)

It will happily do the following:

1. Boot from a business card CD as a live linux distribution (LiveCD)
2. Boot from a USB stick
3. Boot from within a host operating system (that's right, it can run *inside* Windows)
4. Runs very nicely from a Compact Flash drive via "frugal install"
5. Transform into a Debian OS with a traditional hard drive install
6. Run light enough to make an old 486DX with 16MB of Ram into a usefull machine!

You can get it direct from [damnsmalllinux.org](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)It may be a bit long in the tooth but it would be a good place to start..

EDIT:

There is also a newer distro that is based on DSL_Linux called "TinyCore Linux" I use this mostly with newer hardware (misbehaves on some of our 15+ year old gear, DSL_linux does the job)

TinyCORE may well be your best bet if DSL is unsuitable, it is a currently active distro that was last uptated 20th April 2014 so support is available which may be handy. You mentioned BusyBox as a requirement, TinyCore currently has Busybox 1.22.1 If you dont need the X desktop you will get it down to about 8Mb. It is about 12MB with graphical X-desktop,  BusyBox, Tiny X, Fltk, and Flwm. The core runs in RAM and rapid-boots. You control which apps and hardware add support for. (via online repository) Suitable for use on desktops, laptops, netbooks, embedded appliances and servers. (Another techie friend uses TinyCore in 'shivaplug' plugtop computers to operate a wireless mesh network, but I think he is gradually changing over to Raspberry-Pi based units chasing energy efficiency)

You can find TinyCore at [Tiny Core Linux, The Core Project](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/)